# Make first name field unique for User in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a web app with django and I need to make the Users first name unique. I have searched around and it doesnt seem like there is a simple way to do this. The reason i need the first name to be unique is because i am using the first name field as a spotify username field because it makes it convenient because i can use the user creation form.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#unique for a custom User model, or `username` as @IainShelvington suggested for the standard one

Comment: Why not use the `username` field instead since it's already unique and doesn't limit you to having only one user with each first name?

Comment: Why not create a separate field for the spotify username? What difficulty are you specifically having in making the field unique (making a field unique is already well documented and there are also questions on Stack Overflow for this)? Overriding the user model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
```

in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```